# Adding listItem message to SnackBar

Tags: android

What I need to do is, when I press the FAB, it should display the added list item along with the text in the SnackBar. I'm not sure how to do this.

This is the FAB, and at the moment, it only shows "Item added to list" when pressed. It needs to show date/time etc. along with the text.

```
FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            addListItem();
            Snackbar.make(view,  "Item added to list", 
            Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).setAction("Undo", undoOnClickListener).show();

        }
    });
}
```

The item that needs to be shown in the snackbar

```
    private void addListItem() {
    SimpleDateFormat dateformat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss dd/MM/yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH);
    listItems.add(dateformat.format(new Date()));
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
private String addListItem() {
     SimpleDateFormat dateformat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss dd/MM/yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH);
     String formattedDate = dateformat.format(new Date());
     listItems.add(formattedDate);
     adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
     return formattedDate;
 }
```

now below code foe snakbar....

```
  FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            Snackbar.make(view,  "Item added to list "+addListItem(), 
            Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).setAction("Undo", undoOnClickListener).show();

        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> **You can achieve the same by just concatenating data to display:**

```
"Item added to list".concat(" ").concat(listItems.get(listItems.size-1))
```

> **Please check the full snippet below and replace with your code to try:**

```
FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            addListItem();
            Snackbar.make(view,  "Item added to list".concat(" ").concat(listItems.get(listItems.size-1)), 
            Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).setAction("Undo", undoOnClickListener).show();
        }
    });
}
```